# Can't update state in Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**EDIT BELOW**

I'm trying to migrate my states to some contexts so I don't have to constantly prop drill. The problem is, state won't update in the context. I just want a single value in state to be changed to true on click.

Here is my projectTile.js

```jsx
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ProjectContext, ProjectProvider} from './ProjectContext.js';
import {ProjectFunctionsContext, ProjectFunctionsProvider} from './projectFunctionsContext';


// profpic is going to be pulled from the logged in user, for demonstration purposes I just have it pulling the default profile picture right now
import profpic from '../../icon.png';

// projectImage will be passed from the project component, for now it's just a default chosen from the directory.
import defaultProjectImage from '../../defaultProject.jpg';


const ProjectTile = ({projectAuthorName, projectTitle, projectImage,setSavedProjectData}) => {
    
    const [projects, setProjects] = useContext(ProjectContext);
    const [projectClicked, setProjectClicked] = useContext(ProjectFunctionsContext);
    
    

    // Console Log to try to figure out where any errors are coming from, if they arise.
    console.log('Project Author: ' + projectAuthorName + " \n Project Title: " + projectTitle + " \n Project Image: " + projectImage);

    // In this return statement, we build the project tile out of the elements that we're getting from the ProjectContext
    console.log('projectClicked is doing this: ' + projectClicked);
    return (
        <div className="ProjectTile__container" onClick={() => {setProjectClicked(true); console.log(projectClicked);setSavedProjectData({projectAuthorName: projectAuthorName})}}>
            <img src={defaultProjectImage /*projectImage -- this is commented out because it doesn't work at the moment*/} className="ProjectTile__Img" alt="Placeholder"/>
            <div className="ProjectTile__overlay" >
                <img src={profpic} className="ProjectTile__icon" alt="Profile"/>
                <div className="ProjectTile__text">
                    {projectTitle}  
                     <br></br>
                    {projectAuthorName}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
);
}

export default ProjectTile;
```

Here is my projectFunctionsContext.js

```jsx
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react';

export const ProjectFunctionsContext = createContext();

export const ProjectFunctionsProvider = (props) => {
    const [projectClicked, setProjectClicked] = useState(false);
    
    return(
        <ProjectFunctionsContext.Provider 
            value={[projectClicked,setProjectClicked]}
        >
            {props.children}
        </ProjectFunctionsContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

It just won't update projectClicked to true, what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Called the context in parent of this component, making it reset the state.
It happens to work with only one call to get those variables.

Comment: [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) only allows you to get context. You cannot destructure it into `[value, setValue]` like you have in your code. I believe you can only set context via providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the values object in your [ContextProvider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) which allows you to access the properties in your components with the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook.

Your provider should look like this:

```
const contextValue = {
    projectClicked,
    setProjectClicked
};

<ProjectFunctionsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
   {props.children}
</ProjectFunctionsContext.Provider>
```

Then in your components use the useContext hook to retrieve the values stored in context:

```
const { projectClicked, setProjectClicked } = useContext(ProjectFunctionsContext);
```